# How to change the byte array data from Android Camera into a Stream

Tags: android, stream, camera, videochat

I am making a video chat app at Android, and I get the camera data from `Camera.PreviewCallback::onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)`.

But I don't know how to make the byte array "data" into a `Stream` that can be played at the remote machine, or in the local machine by MediaPlayer. Maybe I don't really know what a `Stream` is and what the differences are between a `Stream` and "Frames of data".

Could anyone here help me?

Comment: the "byte[] data" argument means one frame of video data, or we can regard it as an Image, and I want to convert all the Image into a Video Stream

Answer (score -1):

Use this `InputStream is = new ByteA
rrayInputStream(decodedBytes);`

Comment: But this Stream only represents one Frame of data, I want to send a Video Stream rather than one picture to the remote machine.

Comment: then try to convert video file to bytes